# Is there a list explaining the meanings of all TFS version control icon symbols?

Tags: tfs

I am not aware that Microsoft has published a list of TFS icon symbols and their meanings.

It would be helpful to have such a list.

For example, what do the icons mean in the following image?

[image]

My guesses for these two symbols are...

1) green merge symbol means that a merged folder has yet to loaded into the workspace

2) green plus symbol means that a folder created in the workspace has yet to be checked into the server

Comment: This is a simplistic question but what does 'yet to be loaded into the workspace' mean? I have this icon showing for my branch which I have the latest version of and have also checked in the merge onto the server...so why is it there?

Comment: JTech: My guess for that symbol could very well be incorrect or incomplete. I suggest running a "Compare..." on your folders that have this symbol. That may show variances between your workspace and branch applicable to the displayed symbol. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now there is not any **official document** describes the **accurately** meaning of the latest version control icon symbols.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245455.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) explained some version control icons, however it's **out of date**. Some of the icons changed, some of the icons(such as you provided) are not in the table.

It's a good suggestion, I have created a **uservoice** for you. You can vote up for it to get more attention.

> **User Voice Of Team Services**
>
> [Provide a list explaining the meanings of all TFS version control
>   icon symbols(Better Continuous Updates)](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/17112454-provide-a-list-explaining-the-meanings-of-all-tfs)

And for the meanings of the icons you provided, we can only  inferred from the behavior of TFS server. Your guess is correct, a little supplement: green plus symbol also means the changes aleady in *pending changes list*.