# TFS: What does the green icon next to branch mean?

Tags: tfs

I have searched high and low, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40593141/is-there-a-list-explaining-the-meanings-of-all-tfs-version-control-icon-symbols) there is no definitive list of what the icons in TFS mean.

So I thought I would ask this specific question in the hope someone knows the answer and it is helpful for others:

What does this green icon next to a branch mean?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's merge icon. For example, you perform a baseless merge from one branch to another, then in target branch, you'll see this icon.

You can check the pending change type in the right panel when you select this branch:

[image]